# Unable to locate PySpark stdout logs

Tags: apache-spark, logging, pyspark

I'm working on an PySpark application and I deploy it yarn-cluster mode. I have given stdout as the logging streamhandler. I could see the log in YARN UI. However, I couldn't find `stdout` logs under /var/log/sparkapp/yarn. I see only stderr logs there. What could be the reason for this?

This is my logging part in the application

```
import logging
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
lsh = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
lsh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
lformat = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s :%(name)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S')
lsh.setFormatter(lformat)
logger.addHandler(lsh)
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4jspark.root.logger=INFO,console
log4jspark.log.dir=.
log4jspark.log.file=spark.log
log4jspark.log.maxfilesize=1024MB
log4jspark.log.maxbackupindex=10

# Define the root logger to the system property "spark.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${log4jspark.root.logger}, EventCounter

# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead to get the logger for your spark job:

```py
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)
```

You can modify `log4j.properties`to change the `target`file:

```py
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
```